# Непонятный баг с MediaPlayerом в Android

Tags: java, android

```
 @Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    try{
        mediaPlayer.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        mediaPlayer.start();
        videoControllerView.start();
        layoutProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        RequestsRB.putStartWatchingVideo(this, mCourseId, mToken, mLessons.get(currentVideoNum).getId());
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("WatchVideoActivity=onPrepared", "ERRROR" + "");
        if (mediaPlayer==null) Log.e("WatchVideoActivity=onPrepared", "DA1" + "");
        if (mp==null) Log.e("WatchVideoActivity=onPrepared", "DA2" + "");
    }
}
```

Я получил NullPointer в строчке

`if (mediaPlayer==null) Log.e("WatchVideoActivity=onPrepared", "DA1" + "");`

Грубо говоря `mediaPlayer` равен null. А mp не равен null. Дак ведь это одно и тоже. Что за фигня)).

Объясните мне пожалуйста

Кстати mediaPlayer имеет public static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Дак ведь это одно и тоже.

Ну во-первых это не одно и то же. mp передается как параметр в эту переопределенную Вами функцию и скорее всего не null, так как вызывается эта процедура когда готов плеер. А вот mediaPlayer не понятно что это и зачем. 
Если это поле класса, то оно не инициализировано до вызова этой процедуры и надо смотреть выше по коду, где оно должно было инициализироваться и каким образом.

Comment: Оно иницииизированно.

Медиа плеер вызывает onPrepared. через prepareAsync